# What is CHH utility/tool that is used for generating code?

Tags: c++, code-generation

I my current project which is based on C++, I see a part of code which gets generated from a csv file.
It generates both *.cpp and *.h files based on the contents of a csv file.

The actual command is "CHH". When I run it without any arguments, it shows the usage as follows,

```
Running CHH 2.3...
CHH [-Ooutput path] [-Iinput path] [csv] [file1] [file2] [file...]
```

I am having a difficult time figuring out what utility this is.

EDIT:
Example for this command is,

```
CHH -O$HOME/_generatedCode/ -I$HOME/Source/ source.csv source.chh 
source.hhh
```

Here messages.csv is the file that contains comma seperated data and source.hhh will generate *.h files and source.chh will generate *.cpp files based on the definition.

The example contents of source.chh file is as follows,

```
@file ^Classname^.h

#ifndef ^#Classname^_H
#define ^#Classname^_H

class ^Classname^
@@
{
  public:
      ^Classname^();
      ~^Classname^();
@@
      
@foreach ^Type^ ^Attribute^
      ^Type^ ^Attribute^;
@@
};

#endif //^#Classname^_H
```

This will generate *.h file as follows,

```
#ifndef TADA_H
#define TADA_H

class Tada
{
  public:
      Tada();
      ~Tada();

      int MemberVariable1;
      bool MemberVariable2;
      std::string MemberVariable3;
};

#endif //TADA_H
```

PS : I could be wrong with syntax in this example source.hhh and the generated *.h files.

EDIT2:Apparently it's a internal tool. I feel so dumb!

Comment: Could it be this: https://github.com/CHH/optparse

Comment: I found it by searching for "cch command line".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Never mind. Apparently its a internal tool.